# Cannot display HTML5 created by Google Swiffy on Samsung Galaxy series

Tags: html5

I created HTML5 animation by Google Swiffy.
And tryed displaying on Browser with Samsung GalaxyS3(Android4.0) and other Galaxy series, but it was not displayed.
There was no problem in the other devices. (iPhone, other Android4.0)

This problem has occurred from Google Swiffy version7.3.
Do people have to worry about the same phenomenon?
Galaxy series not support HTML5 created by new Google Swiffy?

Comment: スタック・オーバフローへようこそ！このサイトは日本人のためだから、日本語に翻訳してください。

Comment: 日本人のためではなくて、日本語版というのが正しいのでは。

Answer (score -1):

ごめんなさい。
Google Swiffy を使ってアニメーション（SWF）をHTML5に変換します。
Google Swiffyのバージョンは7.3です。
GalaxyS3とGalaxyNoteではブラウザの上で表示したが、黒のままでした。
iPhoneとGalaxy seriesを除いたAndroidでは表示しました。
7.3より前では全て問題ありませんでした。
同じ症状に悩む方はいらっしゃいませんか？

Comment: 質問者であるuser12277と同一の方でしょうか？ もしそうであるなら質問したときのアカウントでログインした上で質問自体を再編集してください。

Comment: もしuser12277にアクセスできない場合、user12282にマージすることも可能ですが、どちらにもアクセスできないのであれば、[アカウントを作成](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/signup)していただいたほうが確実かもしれません。